# Processing Js Animation looking blurry after scaling for retina display

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, retina-display, processing.js

so I have this globe animation. Here is a js fiddle to it.
https://jsfiddle.net/j6sz4e1L/1/

and a screenshot
This first is the working version which is blurry compared to the second one which is not blurry but has 3/4 of its rendering cropped in weirdness.

[image: original blurry version]

[image: non blurry but cropped version]

It works fine but is still slightly blurry until I scale it, then some part of the animation looks weird. The reason I am scaling it is so that it looks clearer on Macbook pro retina. When you comment out the javascript at the end of the script, it works fine without any weirdness but the text doesn't look so much clean.

If anyone has experience with html5 canvas and specifically processing.js, please let me know how to achieve the desired objective (which is to make the text sharper on Retina display) without the weirdness as it is happening now.

Thank you to anyone who took time to look into the question. Here is the code for the javascript I used. It is basically the same as what I have on jsfiddle. The full code can be found in jsfiddle regarding the processing.js part.

## Javascript Code that does the scaling

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("2d"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      processingInstance;
      // desiredWidth = 486,
      // desiredHeight = 432,
    processingInstance = Processing.getInstanceById("2d");

    var desiredWidth = canvas.width,
      desiredHeight = canvas.height,
      scaleFactor = 2;
      canvas.width = desiredWidth * scaleFactor;
      canvas.height = desiredHeight * scaleFactor;
      canvas.style.width = desiredWidth + "px";
      canvas.style.height = desiredHeight + "px";
      // processingInstance.width = desiredWidth * scaleFactor;
      // processingInstance.height = desiredHeight * scaleFactor;
      // processingInstance.scale(2);
      context.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
```

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] instead of your whole project? Just use a single hard-coded word instead of a whole animated globe. Also can you be more specific about what looks off to you? Maybe include screenshots that show the blurriness you're seeing.

Comment: @KevinWorkman ok thank you. I will post just the javascript part that does the scaling. And I will update the screen shots.

Comment: Not really into processingjs so I won't be able to help entirely, but basically, you need to access your processingInstance like you seem to have tried, and to do the scaling there. Don't forget to also call `size()` otherwise `background()` *(and `clear()`?)* won't be scaled. Once it's done, set your canvasElement's style (`size()` will override it). Also, be sure to do all this when the sketch is fully initialized, or it will override all these... Since I didn't found a proper way of doing this later point, I'll leave it as a comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j6sz4e1L/2/

Comment: *Ps:  Might be easier to do all this from the sketch directly?*

Comment: @Kaiido I have just seen your jsfiddle. thank you. I am not clear on your last part where you stated that it willl get overridden if I donot run it after the sketch is fully initialised. Isn't that what the setTimeout is for. Even after setting it to a high value ay 3000, I can see the jscode being applied. It seems to be ok but its just a bit small.could you help me to make it bigger. That might be the solution.

Comment: My point was that the sketch needs to be fully initialized before you do these modifications from js. Yes the setTimeout is there for that, but it's rather unreliable since we don't know how long it will take for the sketch to be completely initialized. As I said I don't know processingjs that much, there may be a way to bind to `setup` from within js, but I don't know this way. IMO, a better solution would be to do all this directly from the p5 sketch.

Comment: Yes something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/j6sz4e1L/3/ sounds cleaner, if you can edit the pde. Made the js function globally available, jsfiddle script is embedded in head, and call it in pde's `setup`.

Comment: @Kaiido seems cleaner. I will research more. seems to have the same effect though.